# Dynamic Programming: Find the Longest Subsequence?

Tags: dynamic-programming, subsequence

In Cormen's Algorithms book, it gave an algorithms for finding the longest subsequene. When filling the table, it started from the lower right corner instead of the upper left corner: In short, it looked for the longest subsequence of two sequences starting from the last elements of both sequence instead of the first elements. Is there a brilliant reason behind this (more efficient,etc.)?

Comment: I think there is no such a special reason for designing an algorithm like that. But if you keep learning dp and algorithm, you will find it's very natural to solve that problem in that way.

Comment: As @Sayakiss said, it is the natural DP thing to do. But you can easily see that there is no functional, algorithmic difference between a string read right-to-left or left-to-right.